# How to merge 2 video files without opening video compression

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming

I need to merge two video files (*.avi) to one video file that will contain both of them (video 2 start at the end of video 1).

I want to do it without opening the video compression in order to make this quick. 
Both files are with same frame size and bit rate.

How to do it?

Comment: Not sure why this bothers me so much, but its merge not marge.  I'm assuming you want to combine the two files and don't want to create "a margin or edge" (according to google)

Comment: You could consider using something like AviDemux and using Process.Start https://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=using:command_line_usage to use it from the command line